# How to toggle that one that is still open in accordion [React, Hooks]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The accordion is just opening one accordion at once, which is nice, but the problem I have now is that the only open one cannot be toggled to closed. It should check the index first and when it is open, it should close the accordion properly if they click on the same label.

```
export const SfAccordion: FC<SfAccordionProps> = ({
  accordionText,
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);

  const openAccordion = (currentIndex) => {
    setActiveIndex(isOpen === currentIndex ? null : currentIndex);
    setOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <Accordion>
      <AccordionCard>
        {accordionText.map(({ content, label }, index) => {
          return (
            <AccordionBlock key={index}>
              <AccordionLabel onClick={() => openAccordion(index)}>
                {label}
              </AccordionLabel>
              <AccordionContent toggle={activeIndex === index}>
                {content}
              </AccordionContent>
            </AccordionBlock>
          );
        })}
      </AccordionCard>
    </Accordion>
  );
};


  accordionText: [
    {
      content: "A user connects the head",
      label: "Accordion Item",
      icon: "./tick.svg",
    },
    {
      content: "A user connects the head",
      label: "Accordion Item",
      icon: "./tick.svg",
    },
    {
      content: "A user connects the head",
      label: "Accordion Item",
      icon: "./tick.svg",
    },
    {
      content: "A user connects the head",
      label: "Accordion Item",
      icon: "./tick.svg",
    },
  ],
```

Comment: what does `toggle={activeIndex === index}` do? is this like isOpen prop?

Comment: I am not sure isOpen === currentIndex is the correct way to go about that, as it would always return false, no? isOpen is a boolean, and currentIndex is a number, so;

true === 1; // returns false
false === 1; // returns false

Comment: Those are all simply divs....

Comment: @Shyam it will open the clicked label while other labels do the opposite...so each click means that there is one accordion open.